# How to change byte order of interpreting response when using python lib minimalmodbus?

Tags: python, modbus

I use python library "minimalmodbus" to communicate with a modbus device:

```
import minimalmodbus
from minimalmodbus import Instrument

minimalmodbus.BAUDRATE = 9600
m = Instrument('com2', 1)
m.debug=True
print m.read_long(4156)
```

the result:

```
MinimalModbus debug mode. Writing to instrument (expecting 9 bytes back): '\x01\x03\x10<\x00\x02\x00\xc7'
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1422431606124.0 ms, minimum silent period: 4.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: '\x01\x03\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\xab\xf3' (9 bytes), roundtrip time: 28.0 ms. Timeout setting: 50.0 ms.
65536
```

the response data is 65536, which is 0x00010000 in hex. But I have already exactly known the data should be 1, 0x00000001 in hex. The reason is obvious: minimalmodbus interpret response data '\x00\x01\x00\x00' as 0x00010000, while for my modbus device supposed to be 0x00000001. I have referred to the documentation(http://minimalmodbus.sourceforge.net/#known-issues) where I saw this:

> For the data types involving more than one register (float, long etc), there are differences in the byte order used by different manufacturers. A floating point value of 1.0 is encoded (in single precision) as 3f800000 (hex). In this implementation the data will be sent as '\x3f\x80' and '\x00\x00' to two consecutive registers. Make sure to test that it makes sense for your instrument. It is pretty straight-forward to change this code if some other byte order is required by anyone (see support section).

I want to ask: Have anyone encountered the same problem and found out an simple and quick method(as the author said) to change the default byte order of minimalmodbus?

**EDIT:**
I have found a way to resolve this problem, but I don't know whether it's the simplest:

```
  def _performCommand(self, functioncode, payloadToSlave):
        '''
        reimplement the _performCommand function in subclass of minimalmodbus.Instrument
        '''          
        payloadFromSlave = Instrument._performCommand(self, functioncode, payloadToSlave)

        if functioncode in [3, 4]:
            #reorder data in response while reading multiple registers
            return payloadFromSlave[0] + self._restructure(payloadFromSlave)
        else:
            return payloadFromSlave

    def _restructure(self, byteCode):
        '''
       reorder byte code for my device, e.g.:
       '\x00\x01\x00\x02'  --->'\x00\x02\x00\x01'
       (byte order may differ for different manufacturers，refer to  http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FAQ.htm#Order)
        '''
        newByteCode = ''
        for i in range(len(byteCode)-2, -1, -2):
            newByteCode += byteCode[i:i+2]
        return newByteCode
```

Comment: A workaround is mentioned here:
https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.org/en/master/advancedusage.html#workaround-for-floats-with-wrong-byte-order

Comment: The workaround in the docs didn't help me. But your solution worked rigth away. Thanks.